# Declaring, updating and accessing a System::String within a class

Tags: .net, string, class, visual-c++, c++-cli

I've been searching since yesterday about my question but I found nothing related to it so far. By the way, I am quite new to classes so please be kind.

I declared a `System::String` variable within a class, I created a method to update that variable and another one that returns it's value. However, updating the said variable throws an exception. What is the correct way of declaring a `System::String` within a class and how do you update and return it's value from a class?

The exception:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in XXX.exe
```

Here is the simplified version of the class I made:

```
ref class clTimeStamp {
public:
    clTimeStamp()
    {
        strDatestamp = gcnew System::String("");
    }
private:
    System::String ^strDatestamp;
public:
    void SetDateStamp(System::String ^a)
    {
        strDatestamp = a->Substring( 6, 4 );    // yyyy
        strDatestamp = strDatestamp + "-" + a->Substring( 3, 2 );
        strDatestamp = strDatestamp + "-" + a->Substring( 0, 2 ) + "T";
    }
    System::String ^GetDateTimeStamp()
    {
        return strDatestamp;
    }
};
```

And this is how I used it in the main program:

```
strBuffer = gcnew String(buffer.c_str());
clTimeStampHSCAN1->SetDateStamp(strBuffer);
fprintf(handle, "%s\n", clTimeStampHSCAN1->GetDateTimeStamp());
```

I am really confused with strings in C++-CLI, there's just too many ways to create them and it gets quite complicated.

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Updated with Caninonos' suggestion (change initialization of String variable in the constructor) but the result is still the same.

Comment: I don't really know C++/CLI (only the standard C++), but you seem to initialize strDatestamp with nullptr, that sounds like  leaving it unallocated. After a quick google search, some results suggest something like `strDatestamp = gcnew System::String` in the constructor instead (if that's indeed the problem).

Comment: @Caninonos I tried what you said and it produced an error upon during build:
`error C2512: 'System::String::String' : no appropriate default constructor available`

Comment: Ah, right, it seems like there is no default constructor (a constructor without any argument) for System::String (cf https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string%28v=vs.110%29.aspx for available constructors).
(i.e. you'll probably have to use something like that instead `strDatestamp = gcnew System::String(' ', 0)` again i'm not really familiar with C++/CLI and this isn't standard C++ so the syntax might be wrong)

Comment: @Caninonos I found a fix to your suggestion but it still threw an exception (same result).

Comment: Please add the exception stack trace to your question.

Comment: Actually [copying](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dabb67x2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1) the [empty string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.empty%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) sounds cleaner. However, i really find these instantiations disturbing, you should probably specify which exception arise, change the tag to c++-cli, and wait for someone more qualified with C++-CLI

Comment: Thanks for the heads up about the tags and exception content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is not in the code you've posted, but the code that's omitted.  Before calling the `SetDateStamp()` member function, you must initialize the clTimeStampHSCAN1 pointer with a clTimeStamp object allocated with gcnew.  Here's an example that works for me.

```
// so_string.cpp : main project file.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>

using namespace System;

ref class clTimeStamp {
public:
    clTimeStamp()
    {
        strDatestamp = nullptr;
    }
private:
    System::String ^strDatestamp;
public:
    void SetDateStamp(System::String ^a)
    {
        strDatestamp = a->Substring( 6, 4 );    // yyyy
        strDatestamp = strDatestamp + "-" + a->Substring( 3, 2 );
        strDatestamp = strDatestamp + "-" + a->Substring( 0, 2 ) + "T";
    }
    System::String ^GetDateTimeStamp()
    {
        return strDatestamp;
    }
};


int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    // This is unmanaged C++
    std::string buffer("01/15/2016 23:00");
    FILE *handle = fopen ("c:\\temp\\myfile.txt" , "w");

    // These are .NET managed objects
    String ^strBuffer = gcnew String(buffer.c_str());
    clTimeStamp ^clTimeStampHSCAN1 = gcnew clTimeStamp();

    clTimeStampHSCAN1->SetDateStamp(strBuffer);
    fprintf(handle, "%s\n", clTimeStampHSCAN1->GetDateTimeStamp());
    return 0;
}
```

Note:  I really wanted to clean up this code, but I decided to keep it largely the same as the original example.  Some things worth looking into for the future would be consistent naming and validation of input.  C++-CLI allow varying levels of abstraction from high-level .Net managed to low level C-style functions close to the hardware.  You have a bit of both mixed together.  I won't go to far into this because that's not the question and this isn't a blog post.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will be looking into this after I finish another requirement I'm working on. I'll respond again with the result.

Comment: Finally got to try your solution and it worked. It's hard to transition from embedded C to Visual C++ and C++/CLI. And you clearly saw that in my code. Embedded C is not as complicated as this. Thanks! `clTimeStamp ^clTimeStampHSCAN1 = gcnew clTimeStamp();` made the program to work.